# My image in html overlap navbar on iphone BUT not on other devices

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, handlebars.js

```
https://gyazo.com/5879a8f4528bcfb7bc5c8b5cd3f72dd1
```

The picture above is a screenshot from my iphone when I test the website. ^

```
https://gyazo.com/5c4ac3d0cef9b63a92f2649d8e00adba
```

The picture above here is from my computer on chrome ^

**The code**

**CSS3**

https://github.com/oskaryil/dev-cafes/blob/master/public/assets/css/main.css#L40-L233

**Html code**

```
<section class="header">
  <div class="nav">
    <div class="nav-left">
      <a href="#" class="nav-title">Dev Cafés</a>
      <a class="nav-location" href="#">
        <i class="fa fa-map-marker" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Stockholm
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-right">
      <a class="nav-add">
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        Add
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>

  </section>
<!-- focus from here -->
<section class="main">

    <div class="cards">
      <ul class="cards-list">
        {{#each venues}}
        <li class="cards-list-item">
          <a href="#" class="cards-link">
            <div class="cards-header-info">


              <div class="cards-header">
                {{#if image}}
                  <img class="blur" src="{{image}}" />
                {{else}}
                  <div class="cards-header-bg">
                  </div>
                {{/if}}
                <p class="cards-header-p">
                  {{name}}, {{adress}}
                </p>
              </div>
 <!-- to here -->
              <div class="cards-info">
                <p>
                  {{description}}
                </p>
                {{#if options.wifi}}
                  <i class="fa fa-wifi availability-icon" data-option="on" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{else}}
                  <i class="fa fa-wifi availability-icon" data-option="off" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                {{/if}}
                {{#if options.toilet}}
                  <svg version="1.1" class="toilet-icon availability-icon" y="0" x="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" data-option="on">
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M146.645,109.31c-54.918,0-55.673,0-101.357,0c-24.466,0-44.468,19.904-44.591,44.367L0,292.109
                          c-0.052,10.407,8.342,18.885,18.747,18.938c0.032,0,0.065,0,0.098,0c10.363,0,18.787-8.375,18.841-18.747l0.696-138.432
                          c0-0.016,0-0.031,0-0.047c0.024-2.055,1.704-3.706,3.759-3.694c2.055,0.012,3.715,1.683,3.715,3.738l0.008,316.757
                          c0,12.488,10.124,22.612,22.612,22.612s22.612-10.124,22.612-22.612V289.888h9.763v180.734c0,12.488,10.123,22.611,22.611,22.611
                          s22.611-10.123,22.611-22.611c0-298.894-0.4-127.966-0.41-316.481c0-2.121,1.674-3.863,3.794-3.946
                          c2.12-0.083,3.928,1.521,4.092,3.635c0,0.001,0,0.002,0,0.002l-0.128,138.354c-0.01,10.406,8.419,18.851,18.825,18.861
                          c0.007,0,0.011,0,0.018,0c10.397,0,18.833-8.426,18.842-18.825l0.128-138.431c0.002-0.039,0.002-0.075,0.001-0.114
                          C191.112,129.214,171.109,109.31,146.645,109.31z"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <circle cx="95.966" cy="57.813" r="39.047"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M510.941,262.849c-0.346-0.986-34.611-98.717-40.002-114.406c-8.679-25.253-23.23-38.057-43.249-38.057
                          c-28.025,0-37.18,0-65.153,0c-20.02,0-34.571,12.805-43.249,38.057c-5.391,15.688-39.656,113.421-40.002,114.406
                          c-3.418,9.748,1.714,20.423,11.464,23.841c9.758,3.42,20.425-1.725,23.84-11.462c1.106-3.154,21.721-60.433,33.222-93.389
                          c-1.204,9.838,2.264-10.578-26.737,139.154c-1.246,6.431,3.711,12.379,10.201,12.379c4.029,0,8.862,0,14.273,0v135.678
                          c0,12.396,10.049,22.446,22.446,22.446c12.397,0,22.446-10.049,22.446-22.446v-135.68c3.227,0,6.465,0,9.692,0v135.68
                          c0,12.396,10.049,22.446,22.446,22.446c12.397,0,22.446-10.049,22.446-22.446v-135.68c5.411,0,10.245,0,14.273,0
                          c6.522,0,11.446-5.952,10.201-12.379c-28.737-148.369-25.57-131.138-26.55-139.154c11.593,33.211,31.602,90.284,32.691,93.389
                          c3.421,9.756,14.101,14.878,23.84,11.462C509.227,283.27,514.359,272.597,510.941,262.849z"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <circle cx="395.283" cy="59.265" r="38.767"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M239.761,43.925c-7.969,0-14.43,6.46-14.43,14.43v395.282c0,7.969,6.46,14.429,14.43,14.429
                          c7.97,0,14.43-6.459,14.43-14.429V58.355C254.191,50.385,247.73,43.925,239.761,43.925z"/>
                    </svg>
                {{else}}
                  <svg version="1.1" class="toilet-icon availability-icon" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 512 512" xml:space="preserve" data-option="off">
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M146.645,109.31c-54.918,0-55.673,0-101.357,0c-24.466,0-44.468,19.904-44.591,44.367L0,292.109
                          c-0.052,10.407,8.342,18.885,18.747,18.938c0.032,0,0.065,0,0.098,0c10.363,0,18.787-8.375,18.841-18.747l0.696-138.432
                          c0-0.016,0-0.031,0-0.047c0.024-2.055,1.704-3.706,3.759-3.694c2.055,0.012,3.715,1.683,3.715,3.738l0.008,316.757
                          c0,12.488,10.124,22.612,22.612,22.612s22.612-10.124,22.612-22.612V289.888h9.763v180.734c0,12.488,10.123,22.611,22.611,22.611
                          s22.611-10.123,22.611-22.611c0-298.894-0.4-127.966-0.41-316.481c0-2.121,1.674-3.863,3.794-3.946
                          c2.12-0.083,3.928,1.521,4.092,3.635c0,0.001,0,0.002,0,0.002l-0.128,138.354c-0.01,10.406,8.419,18.851,18.825,18.861
                          c0.007,0,0.011,0,0.018,0c10.397,0,18.833-8.426,18.842-18.825l0.128-138.431c0.002-0.039,0.002-0.075,0.001-0.114
                          C191.112,129.214,171.109,109.31,146.645,109.31z"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <circle cx="95.966" cy="57.813" r="39.047"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M510.941,262.849c-0.346-0.986-34.611-98.717-40.002-114.406c-8.679-25.253-23.23-38.057-43.249-38.057
                          c-28.025,0-37.18,0-65.153,0c-20.02,0-34.571,12.805-43.249,38.057c-5.391,15.688-39.656,113.421-40.002,114.406
                          c-3.418,9.748,1.714,20.423,11.464,23.841c9.758,3.42,20.425-1.725,23.84-11.462c1.106-3.154,21.721-60.433,33.222-93.389
                          c-1.204,9.838,2.264-10.578-26.737,139.154c-1.246,6.431,3.711,12.379,10.201,12.379c4.029,0,8.862,0,14.273,0v135.678
                          c0,12.396,10.049,22.446,22.446,22.446c12.397,0,22.446-10.049,22.446-22.446v-135.68c3.227,0,6.465,0,9.692,0v135.68
                          c0,12.396,10.049,22.446,22.446,22.446c12.397,0,22.446-10.049,22.446-22.446v-135.68c5.411,0,10.245,0,14.273,0
                          c6.522,0,11.446-5.952,10.201-12.379c-28.737-148.369-25.57-131.138-26.55-139.154c11.593,33.211,31.602,90.284,32.691,93.389
                          c3.421,9.756,14.101,14.878,23.84,11.462C509.227,283.27,514.359,272.597,510.941,262.849z"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <circle cx="395.283" cy="59.265" r="38.767"/>
                      </g>
                    </g>
                    <g>
                      <g>
                        <path d="M239.761,43.925c-7.969,0-14.43,6.46-14.43,14.43v395.282c0,7.969,6.46,14.429,14.43,14.429
                          c7.97,0,14.43-6.459,14.43-14.429V58.355C254.191,50.385,247.73,43.925,239.761,43.925z"/>
                    </svg>
                {{/if}}
              </div>
              </div>
          </a>
        </li>
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JSON object with data that gets sent to handlebars**

```
 module.exports = [
  {

        name: 'Starbucks Stureplan',
        adress: 'Kungsgatan 2',
        description: 'Very nice place with good drinks and good wifi with nice service.',
        options: {
          wifi: true,
          toilet: true
        },
//this is the image
        image: "https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/8f/5f/d0/8f5fd07d1034e0d4941c4ad9d58ec055.jpg"
      },
      {
        name: 'Starbucks Fenix',
        adress: 'Kungsgatan 2',
        description: 'Very nice place with good drinks and good wifi with nice service.',
        options: {
          wifi: true,
          toilet: true
        }
      }
    ]
```

**NOTE this is a mobile first approach**

One thing that solves it is if you remove the picture but I need the picture. Also it is not possible to have it as background in css because then the whole point of using handlebars dissapear.

You can fix it by putting a "margin-top: 130px" on the "main" section but then when you use it on android the "main" section will be 130px below the navbar.

I really don't understand why this problem occurs.

Comment: I cannot see the photo for the iPhone image, it says I need to login to access it. Please host it elsewhere so people aren't required to login. Also, you can add images directly into your post.

Comment: ah sorry, fixed it now

Comment: I would go with @AnthonyMichelizzi suggestion of doing a browser specific check. Each browser renders differently and without having a working example of your issue it is really hard to figure out what is wrong. The code provided is good but it is hard to make relationships between what is what and if anything else if affecting it. Best of luck!

Answer (score 0):

The website itself works fine in chrome, but not in safari, so you can detect the specific `navigator.userAgent` and modify the element and css like so.

```
if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 &&
navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") == -1) {
$("h1").addClass("safari");
}
```

I have made a js fiddle for you

https://jsfiddle.net/01obbpwv/1/

Edit: forgot to add jQuery to the fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it without using js, you had to wrap the img tag in another div like this:

```
<div class="child-img">


              {{#if image}}
                <img class="blur" src="{{image}}" />
              {{else}}
                <div class="cards-header-bg">
                </div>
              {{/if}}
</div>
```

That solved it, then in this case you put `display: inherit;` in the css!